# Animation in Android EditText Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to create an animated TextInput layout for my login page but I cant't make it work.

below are the pictures of what I am trying to do:

image when you arrive on the login page:

[image]

when you start typing the email, the line length should decrease when email address is typed, the more you type the smaller the line became.

[image]

Here is the layout I have created but it's not working.

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/gainsboro_00"
                android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                android:hint="@string/email">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/transparent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/email_et"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textColor="@color/gainsboro_00"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:minWidth="75dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/email_line"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/checkered_gainsboro_background"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/email_et"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Any idea how to achieve this? I think I am not far from the solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ConstraintLayout and View elements inside TextInputLayout.

Documentation is here: https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the OP issue! Probably this can answer another question.

Answer (score 0):

Material Design provides you instant EditText with Animation. You simply need to change the `style` of the `TextInputLayout` as shown below in the code.

Here is the code you can use as per your requirements.

```xml
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/enter_your_email_id"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            android:id="@+id/edtEmailID"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_below="@id/welcomeText"
            app:endIconTint="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:hintTextColor="#000">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editEmailIn"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Refer to [Documentation](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field) for better exposure